# An home moving company moves unknown number of pieces of furniture. Formula for the probability that 2 specific pieces are moved first?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> A home moving company transports is transporting several pieces of
>   furniture to a building, among which there are 2 pool tables.
>
> The total number of pieces of furniture is unknown. Each piece is
>   transported in a random order, one at the time. What is the
>   probability that the two first pieces being transported are the pool
>   tables?
>
> A) $\frac{1}{^nC_2}$
>
> $$\\$$
>
> B) $\frac{2(n-2)!}{^nC_2}$

A clue: even though it is not stated, I *assume* the order doesn't matter. This is because I first solved the problem that way and it worked.

I already solved this problem by writing an expression for the probability and then comparing it to the 2 options. For example, for option A I did:

$$\frac{2}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{1}{^nC_2}$$
$$\frac{2}{n^2-n} = \frac{1}{\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}}$$
$$\frac{2}{n^2-n} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$$
$$\frac{2}{n^2-n}  = \frac{2}{n^2-n} $$

Luckily, the right option was option A) so I didn't have to spend too much time solving this.

My question is, is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: The probability that the first piece is a "winner" is $\frac 2n$.  Conditioned on that, the probability that the second is also a winner is $\frac 1{n-1}$.  Now multiply.

Comment: @lulu $\frac{2}{n^2-n}$ ? That's what I did

Comment: Many people are able to recognize $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ as being equal to $\binom{n}{2}$ in a single step and thus $\frac{2}{n(n-1)}$ as being equal to $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}$.  Of course, this comes with practice and familiarity with how the binomial coefficients look in different representations.  If you wanted to be explicit, then what you did is fine, though I would have written it as one long equality instead of running two parallel like you did.

Comment: My method avoids reference to combinations and binomial symbols, but of course it comes to the same thing.  It's barely one line long...I don't think there's a faster way!

Comment: @lulu the OP got the correct answer and did it in exactly the way you suggest.  His question seems more related to how to show $\frac{2}{n^2-n}$ is in fact equal to $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}$ in order to have it match the answers given in multiple choice.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, I see. Thanks

Comment: @JMoravitz  So I see (upon closer reading).    Well, to do it with combinations one might just remark that there are only one winning pair out of $\binom n2$ possibles, hence the other form.  Actually, I thought this was the way the OP had solved the problem.